# How do I create a prefabs when a button is clicked(Unity)

Tags: unity

So I want to be able to spawn prefabs when a button is pressed

Shop script -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string Item01;
    public static string Item02;
    public static string Item03;
    public static string Item04;

    public static int ShopNum; 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(ShopNum == 1) {
            Item01 = "Cannon";
            Item02 = "Tower";
            Item03 = "army Camp";
            Item04 = "Baracks";
        }
        if(ShopNum == 2) {
            Item01 = "Archer";
            Item02 = "Barbarian";
            Item03 = "Goblin";
            Item04 = "Wizard";
        }
    }
}
```

And then my Shop Access script -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Shop01Access : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ShopInventory;
    public GameObject Item01Text;
    public GameObject Item02Text;
    public GameObject Item03Text;
    public GameObject Item04Text;
    public GameObject ItemCompletion;
    public GameObject CompleteText;


    void OnTriggerEnter() {
        ShopInventory.SetActive(true);
        Screen.lockCursor = false;
        Shop.ShopNum = 1;
        Item01Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + Shop.Item01;
        Item02Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + Shop.Item02;
        Item03Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + Shop.Item03;
        Item04Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + Shop.Item04;
    }


    public void Item01(){
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy" + Shop.Item01 + "?";
    }
    public void Item02(){
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy" + Shop.Item02 + "?";
    }
    public void Item03(){
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy" + Shop.Item03 + "?";
    }
    public void Item04(){
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy" + Shop.Item04 + "?";
    }

    public void Cancel(){
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

How could I spawn a cannon when button item01 is pressed into my 3d scene

Answer (score 1):

First, in your `Shop` you do not need to spam the assignment of `Item01-04` in the `Update()`. If the value does not change, doing once in `Start()` is enough. If your Shop can change the sortiment, you can assign the new values when you assign the new `ShopNum`.

There is another problem with your reference to Shop. First your class is not static. Second it makes not much sense to just change it each time you try to access the text. You probably want to reference to the actual object of your Item to access more of it stats/ images/ prices besides the name.

What you are looking for is [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Now if I read your `Shop01Access` correctly, you want to have a small dialog to confirm the action. (Besides the need to check if the Player has enough funds to actually be able to afford the item). There is as well the problem, where do you want to spawn the Object? Just spawning it `Instantiate(prefab);`. But that is not really helpful as it is, usually you need to provide the location and rotation. It helps as well with organizing if you parent it to another GameObject in the scene to have all your spawned objects together.

Another thing you might want to take a look at are Arrays. You repeat a lot of things that are exactly the same besides the name. Instead of

```
public GameObject Item01Text;
public GameObject Item02Text;
public GameObject Item03Text;
public GameObject Item04Text;
```

You can write

```
public GameObject[] ItemText;
```

And access it with the number

```
CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy" + ItemText[0] + "?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a something like this and link it to the button in the OnClick window in properties:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // GameObject to be instantiated on click
    public GameObject instantiatedGameObject;

    // Function to be called on button click
    public void SpawnItem()
    {
        Instantiate(instantiatedGameObject, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```